# How do I call my own Android reinforcements in XCOM Chimera Squad?

Tags: xcom-chimera-squad

I have 2 android reinforcements(named Prince and Ice) available but they never show up when an agent is down during a mission.

I read a Reddit post saying that if I have an agent "knocked off", an Android will automatically replace their place for the end of the mission. - This never happened.

Another I read(also XCOM handbook/guide? inside the game), says "when an agent evacuates" an android will replace the agent.

But this is my situation.

1. I completed the research to allow myself to buy an android.
2. I bought 2 androids.
3. In one mission, I had 3 agents down and stabilised.
4. No android reinforcements...

My question is, how exactly do I trigger an android reinforcement to come in?

For "when an agent evacuates" - how does an agent that is stabilised from bleeding out can evacuate on their own??

I also tried to send an intact agent next to the stabilised agent to see if I can pick up the stabilised agent and call evac. No evac icon was there for me to activate.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The way it works is if one of your agents goes down, the android comes as reinforcements in the next encounter. So you have to wait until you beat the current encounter before it asks you to deploy it.

Comment: This doesn't work for me, I just end up with a man down (stabilised) in the next mission, so far I have had multiple occasions where I have members stabilised, but still no androids in the next encounter.

Comment: It may turn in the future that an effective evacuation will come in, however currently there is no need for evacuation. I had 3 of my agents go down in last round, and killed last enemy. Next encounter I was offered to select the android to step in.